# Replacing parts of a string using Excel Formula

Tags: excel

I got a string that Looks like this:

```
015-02-1-1
```

I want to replace the "015" by "019".
But the String can also be:

```
016-14-5-7
```

in this case the "016" should be replaced by "018"

Here is a List of all Values that should be replaced:

```
015 => 019
016 => 018
018 => 016
019 => 020
020 => 021
021 => 022
022 => 023
023 => 024
```

The Rest of the String (everything after the first dash) should stay the same. Can this be realized using a Formula, or does this require VBA?

If so, how would that Formula look?

Comment: This _could_ be done with a pure Excel formula, but it would be very ugly and also error prone.  I would probably go with VBA if this is accessible to you.  Or any editor with regex capabilities would also work.

Comment: My data is an Excel File, so I'd like to stay in Excel. I'll try to develop a VBA Sub for this.

Comment: Can you confirm that only the second and third digits of the string require changing or will there be required changes elsewhere in the string?

Comment: Can confirm @5202456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a formula that will work assuming that your data is starting in cell G1:

```
=LEFT(G1,1)&IF(MID(G1,2,2)="15",19,IF(MID(G1,2,2)="16",18,IF(MID(G1,2,2)="18",16,IF(MID(G1,2,2)="19",20,IF(MID(G1,2,2)="20",21,IF(MID(G1,2,2)="21",22,IF(MID(G1,2,2)="22",23,IF(MID(G1,2,2)="23",24,""))))))))&RIGHT(G1,LEN(G1)-3)
```

How it works, find the first character of the string left(G1,1)

Use nested ifs to change the values, use mid to find the values we want to change, as the string is treated as text we have to use "" to reference the value.

Then add the rest of the string back, find the length of G1 string with len then minus 3, this value is used to find the right most characters of the string to join them back together.

Comment: It says there is a Problem with this Formula

Comment: It is working for me, please can you confirm that your data is in cells A1,A2,A3 and so-forth, also what version of excel you are using?  Is there any details given about the error?

Comment: No Details given. using Excel 2016 and the String to split is in Column G

Comment: Have you changed the formula to reference the cells in column G starting at the first row of data?

Comment: I have changed the formula in my answer to work now with data in column G, starting at G1

Comment: That is exactly what I did too, but I still get the same error message

Comment: Sorry, I found the Error. I dont have english Excel so it simply could find the functions you used, because it exspects the functions in my language. Sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You could also go for a lookup approach like this

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(LEFT(A1,3),{"015","016","018","019","020","021","022","023";"019","018","016","020","021","022","023","024"},2,FALSE),LEFT(A1,3))&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>